# Make a triangle shape in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to print out the shape of a triangle but I am kinda lost...

this is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()    
{
    int i, k, n;

    cout << "Please enter number of rows you want to see: \n";
    cin >> n;
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            cout << '*';
        cout << endl;
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: What is the desired and actual output?

Comment: this does print a triangle.

Comment: @imtheman  There there is a different triangle.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works fine for a right angled triangle -

```
*
**
***
```

*But I guess you want a triangle like this* -

```
  *
 ***
*****
```

*Try this* -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i, j, k, n;
    cout << "Please enter number of rows you want to see: \n";
    cin >> n;
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++)
    {
       for(j = 1; j <= n-k; j++)
            cout << ' ';
       for (i = 1; i <= 2*k-1; i++)
            cout << '*';
       cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think the code is pretty straightforward to understand. The *first* inner `for` loop is to print the spaces and the *second* inner `for` loop is to print the `*`

Answer (score 0):

This does print the shape of a triangle. For example, when you put in 5, the program outputs

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

If your computer isn't printing this output, it's not a problem with your code.